# "Global Load Efficiency" over 100%

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia, kepler

I have a CUDA program in which threads of a block read elements of a long array in several iterations and memory accesses are almost fully coalesced. When I profile, *Global Load Efficiency* is over 100% (between 119% and 187% depending on the input). Description for *Global Load Efficiency* is "*Ratio of global memory load throughput to required global memory load throughput.*" Does it mean that I'm hitting L2 cache a lot and my memory accesses are benefiting from it?

My GPU is GeForce GTX 780 (Kepler architecture).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question at NVIDIA forum [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/628818/cuda-programming-and-performance/-ldquo-global-load-efficiency-rdquo-over-100-in-visual-profiler/post/3992785/#3992785). I quote the answer I got:

*"Global Load Efficiency and Global Store Efficiency describe how well the coalescing of DRAM-accesses and (L2?)Cache-accesses works. If they're 100 percent then you've got perfect coalescing. Since efficiencies above 100 percent don't make any sense (you cannot be better than optimal) this has to be an error. 
This error is caused by the Visual Profiler, which counts hardware events to calculate some abstract metrics. But the GPU doesn't have the "correct" events to exactly calculate all those metrics, thus Visual Profiler has to estimate those metrics by using some complex formula and "wrong" events. There are some metrics which are just rough estimations and Global Load Efficiency and Global Store Efficiency are two of them. Thus if such an efficiency is bigger than 100 percent it is an estimation error. As far as I observed the Global Load Efficiency and Global Store Efficiency both increased above 100 percent in some of my register spilling kernels. That's why i assume that the Visual-Profiler uses some events, which also may be caused by local memory accesses, to calculate those two efficiencies. Furthermore GPUs just uses 32 Bit Counters. Thus long running kernel tend to overflow those counters, which also causes the Visual Profiler to display wrong metrics."*